# how to free codeigniter results while calling the same model twice

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a situation, I have written a base model in codeigniter, all models extend from it, the base model has a function

```
public function load_all_by_keys($array, $limit = 0, $offset = 0) {
  if ($limit) {
    $query = $this->database->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, $array, $limit, $offset);
  } else {
    $query = $this->database->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, $array);
  }
  $ret_val = array();
  $class = get_class($this);
  foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $model = new $class;
    $model->populate($row);
    $ret_val[$row->{$this::DB_TABLE_PK}] = $model;
  }
  return $ret_val;
}
```

in this function I am able to get lets say for instance, schools which are of category Abet

```
$abet = new School_Model();
// this query will get all schools with by column category whose value is Abet, thats fine
$abetSchools = $abet-?load_all_by_keys(array('category'=>'Abet'));
$primary = new School_Model();
// This second query fails with the error Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object
$primarySchools = $primary-?load_all_by_keys(array('category'=>'Primary'))
```

Can someone help

Comment: What version of codeIgniter are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->flush_cache()
```

This function deletes all items from the Active Record cache (Reference http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#caching)